# R Function to find and remove a string with its given numerical range

Tags: arrays, string, gsub

I have a column named "edited_address" in a df named CB_Edit. In "edited_address" column there are a multitude of addresses. Some addresses include a variable ("L#") which I want to completely remove from all of them which possess it. For instance:

edited_address:

```
100 S Smith Street
200 S Smith L100 Street
300 S Smith Street
400 S L1 Smith Street
500 S Smith Street L999
600 N Jacobs Blvd
900 L53 Cascades Street
```

I want to remove the "L#" from the column. There are two problems. The first is that the L followed by the number range anywhere from 0-9999. The second is that the L# can be anywhere in the column cell. Let me know what I can do, thank you!

As a side, there are numerous outliers for this problem, here are some examples. These numeric ranges are from 1-9999 and have a second letter from A-Z. These second letters sometimes also possess their own number range:

```
L1A thru L9999Z

as well as 

L1A1 thru L9999Z9999
```

I have tried several gsub functions, expecting to capture everything in the range. That did not happen.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following approach with `sub()`, for a base R option:

```r
df$edited_address <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", sub("\\s*\\bL\\d{1,4}\\b\\s*", " ", df$edited_address))
df

      edited_address
1 100 S Smith Street
2 200 S Smith Street
3 300 S Smith Street
4 400 S Smith Street
5 500 S Smith Street
```

For your updated question I would match on this regex pattern:

```
\s*\bL\d{1,4}(?:[A-Z]\d{0,4})?\b\s*
```

Comment: Hello! This worked out great. I have very few outliers that I didn't realize the first time (like L92A or L5334D6). If you could explain how your code works or why, that would be fantastic since I could edit it further to try to pick up the remaining few. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really edit because you might reveal other outliers still.  If you can edit your question and show all `Lxxx` values you need to remove, I might be able to edit my regex pattern.

Comment: I have now updated my question! Thank you Tim

Comment: I have given you an updated regex pattern.